# Notations inside inside other notations problem in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code to write a new file but I'm having problems with the content because I'm not able to write "" inside "". What should I do?

```
$done = fwrite (
    $fp,
    "<html><p id="fn"></p><script>document.getElementById ("fn").innerHTML = fn;</script></html>"
);
```

Comment: Escape the inner quotes with a backslash: `\"`. Or use single quotes on the outside.

Comment: Do i have to type a single notation on the beginning and the end? Like '<html> and "" inside and </html>' ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

`$fn = "foobar";
$done = fwrite ($fp , "<html><p id='$fn'></p><script>document.getElementById ('$fn').innerHTML = '$fn'; </script> </html>");`

But watch out you can use directly $variable inside " ", where with ' ' you need to connect your variable because otherwise you see $fn in there

`$fn = "foobar";
echo '<p id="'+$fn+'"></p>';`

hope this helps :)

Comment: Do you have a better idea to create a user profile webpage upon he/she signsup (I use firebase database)

Comment: Better look at some templates/snippets, I'm pretty sure there should be something out there ;)